# How can I reuse a server-side TCP endpoint for multiple consumers?

Tags: tcp, websocket, rust

I'm a beginner trying to understand TCP, and I'm using Rust. If I create a new listener and bind it to an address

```
let tcplistener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:55555").unwrap();
```

I can `tcplistener.accept()` new connections between `127.0.0.1:55555` and some other endpoint on the client.

In my case, `tcplistener` lives within an instance of a struct representing a plugin. Each plugin should be controllable from its own browser tab. There is one connection (endpoint-pair) per plugin, with one endpoint always being `127.0.0.1:55555`. The plugins run in a single thread with non-blocking listeners and streams. I use websockets, but I'm not sure if this question is specific to websockets.

What I'm doing now is

- instantiate plugin A
- accept the first connection from a browser tab to plugin A
- after that, assign the `tcplistener` field in plugin A to a newly created listener with arbitrary OS-assigned port

This seems to work; if I instantiate a new plugin B afterwards, I can create a listener bound to `127.0.0.1:55555` and accepting a connection. If I don't create a new listener with different address/port, then I get the "Address already in use" error.

**This is obviously not a good solution since it occupies all the other ports for no reason. Is there a better way?**

A comment said:

> Why does each plugin have a `TcpListener`? Why not have one component with the listener, call `accept`, then hand off the returned `TcpStream` to each constructed plugin?

That does sound good, but where would that `TcpListener` be stored, and how does it hand off the streams? Possibilities I see for storing:

- The host. I cannot modify the plugin host, I'm just a plugin author.
- One dedicated plugin. The problem I see is that plugins can't access any information stored in another plugin, so I wouldn't know how to do that.
- A separately running process. I could imagine running a server separately and let the plugins be clients. Users could connect their browser to the server, which somehow does the proxying to the plugin. Sounds reasonable, but the inconvenience here is that plugin users would have to install a server as a separate package. So I'd really like to avoid that. Although I suppose launching the server could be done automatically at plugin instantiation, maybe that's the way to go?

Comment: The first suggestion (Option<>) works! That's truly awesome! I haven't understood the nature of Option<> at all, I must read the docs more thoroughly. So far used it only for null pointers. How can I accept this as an answer? Regarding the suggestion of instantiation: Interesting point, I have not fully thought it through. My guess is that instantiation can be done only from the host. If it *is* technically possible, it is unusual in that I have not seen it elsewhere (granted, that doesn't mean much, I'm a beginner). BTW, this is all about the LV2 audio plugin standard.

Comment: You may be interested in https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/61h21t/writing_an_audio_plugin_in_rust/

Comment: Thanks for the link, that looks interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround, if I understand all of your limitations correctly, is to use [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html). `Option` is used for precisely the case of "something or not something".

Here, you could have an `Option<TcpListener>`. On a freshly-initialized plugin, this would be set to `Some(...)`, and once accepted, would transition to `None`.

This does have a number of downsides:

- There's a time period where there are no listeners.
- You have to deal with the possibility of the listener being `None`.
- You can't start a second plugin before the first one accepts something.

Some kind of parent-child relationship is probably better, or even limiting to a singleton plugin, if plausible.

Comment: Option<>, yes! Good points about the downsides. In particular the third one, I haven't thought about that at all. Thanks for your help!